# Restoring Android Activity playing media

Tags: android, android-activity, media-player

I'm working on a project that includes a media player. All is going fine, I select the media to be played from a play list and send it to the player activity and press play. The audio plays just like it should. Now, when I leave that activity (with the audio still playing) I'm unable to get back to that same activity, clicking the same item from the playlist starts a new activity with the old media playing in the background still. How can bring back an old activity?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your question at all. However, look at the state diagram here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

And the other state diagram here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Combine the MediaPlayer states and the Activity states in order to fulfill your need.

Comment: i don't want to start a new activity each time the app calls for it. if its already been started I want to bring it back on top.

Comment: I'm not saying you should start a new activity. Rather, you should understand the stages and states an app goes through when you close it, return to it, it gets closed by android, etc... When the app is killed (and therefore it should be started again) doesn't depend on you, but on the device's available memory.